# Build with ffmpeg : make: *** No rule to make target 'jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c', needed al/arm64-v8a/objs/lame/VbrTag.o'. Stop

Tags: android, ffmpeg, ndk-build

my [jni folder](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme/tree/master/app/src/main/jni)
[image]

[Android.mk file](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk)

lame folder

[image]
when I build ndk it comes like this.

[image]

After, I added the lame in third_party/lame there was 16 warnings and 2 errors generated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: The project you linked does not have this `third_party` directory. Did you check out "lame" and put it in the right place?

Comment: How to set the third_party directory

Comment: You need to check out the [lame](https://github.com/zlargon/lame) project and put it at `src/main/third_party/lame`. This is what the error is telling you: it cannot find the file because the whole tree is missing.

Comment: in my obj file the lame is present and I already linked with my android.mk file.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: You read "some warnings and errors" and you fix them. The site I linked tells you how to fix the error regarding iee754_float32_t, you can probably ignore the warnings.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I successfully generated the lame. But , I have the some errors in my ffmpeg-jni.c code. Here, it is my question     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926310/avcodec-encode-video-avcodec-encode-audio-av-new-stream-is-deprecated